Find and Replace function missing in Jupyter Notebook
I recently had to install jupyter notebook on a new virtual machine. On my old VM, I was able to click the edit menu and scroll all the way down to find a function labeled "find and replace". This function was very useful because it allowed me to isolate the find and replace function to a single cell. The menu looked like this:Find & Replace - Original
This is no longer available on my new VM. I installed Jupyter Notebook the exact same way as before. It has been replaced with a find and replace function that looks like this: Find & Replace - New
Which is incredibly limited because it only allows replacement throughout the whole document. Is there a way to get the first version back?
I tried searching for a solution on other stackoverflow threads but I did not find any instances of other people having this issue, thus I couldn't find a fix. I'm not sure what's going on because I assumed this function was supposed to be included by default.

In Jupyter Notebook 7, click the Filter icon to the right of the Find field. It looks like a funnel

There will be a "Search in Selection" filter.  If you have several cells selected, it will say "Search in # cells", or if you have several lines selected it will say "Search in # lines".
Information found in this Jupyter forum post about the change to Find & Replace
